# Why is_installed() function does not work?

Tags: r

I am trying to use `is_installed()` function in order to see if my `MASS` package is installed or not? However, I get the following ERROR message that `is_installed function not found...`
Why is that? My R version is 4.0.2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rlang::is_installed` but more easily (and this is what that function does anyway) use `requireNamespace(x, quietly = TRUE)` where `x` is the package name.